# How do I factory reset a MacBook air that came with Monterey when the recovery systems plist is set to El Capitan?

Tags: macos

This is a MacBook air that had Monterey 12.3, I plugged in an old USB of El Capitan with the intent to upgrade through app store after install. Now the systems preference plist is set to El Capitan. So the recovery attempts to install this and apple server rejects the device as unsupported. This should be valid device that was running Monterey fine, but I wanted to reinstall. The person I bought this from had reset with a blank user password but wasn't aware what of the su password.

Can I somehow edit the plist, which vim opens as read-only, or otherwise reinstall to Monterey?

Comment: Why can't you just use internet recovery & wipe the drive entirely?

Comment: Because now the internet recovery attempts to install El Capitan, which fails. I can see the plist pointing to 10.11.6 now, which is too old for this device, but I cannot even edit the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@crazyfox - I believe you should be able to reinstall Monterey with a bootable installer.

Here's a link to an Apple support article that describes the process:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372.

Here's a YouTube link as well that steps through the process:
https://youtu.be/rgHyvj_nWCU.